# iPad Charging USB Hub?

Tags: ipad, mac, usb, charging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When I plug my iPad into my computer USB ports, iPad displays “Not Charging”.  What can I do?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274/when-i-plug-my-ipad-into-my-computer-usb-ports-ipad-displays-not-charging-wh)

Newer MacBooks provide enough juice through the built-in USB ports for the iPad to charge quickly, and one can use the wall outlet to get the job done as well. However, there don't seem to be any hubs out there that do anything but trickle-charge...

Is anyone aware of a USB hub that can charge an iPad? I'd really like to be able to sync & charge at the same time without having to plug in directly into the MacBook.

Comment: I don't have a particular model in mind, but every USB hub has a different "power brick". Find the ones that have more power. Although it may seem like every hub is the same, truth is that some are more expensive  (and thus deliver more power) than others.

Comment: Congratulations to the moderator on closing the question. What "exact duplicate" pray tell this is? And as long as someone can name an actual hub that charges the iPad, like the MacBook does, this is a valid and open question.

Comment: Up above, there's a section that says **"Possible Duplicate"** with a link. If you go to the linked question, [When I plug my iPad into my computer USB ports, iPad displays "Not Charging". What can I do?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274/when-i-plug-my-ipad-into-my-computer-usb-ports-ipad-displays-not-charging-wh), you should see that the actual question is **Are there external USB hubs that can supply enough power to charge the iPad?** — and isn't that what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 3):

Apple's online store sells two Belkin USB hubs with support for "high-power devices":

> Power: Max. power output per port: 500mAh

- [Belkin USB 4-port Hub * Stellar](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H1827VC/A)
- [Belkin USB 7-port Hub * Stellar](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H1828VC/A)

Comment: I don't know about the 4-port, but the 7-port you linked to specifically says, "(Note that the hub cannot charge iPad and iPhone 4)." "High-power" means (as you pointed out) 500mAh, but the iPad requires significantly higher.

Comment: @Dori Ah, missed that part. Darn. 500mA is the max supported by the USB spec, so anything higher is Apple doing their own, non-standard thing. What's even more odd is I my iPhone 4 charges just fine on my Belkin USB hub that I got for $30 at Best Buy several years ago.

Comment: @Ky;e - iPhone 4s don't need anywhere the amount of power that the iPads do to charge (sadly).

Comment: @Dori Right, which is why the "cannot charge ... iPhone 4" part is confusing