# iPad will not charge

Tags: charging

I can transfer data from trough a genuine Apple cable from my iPad to a PC but the same cable will not allow my iPad or iPhone 4s to charge battery using a multi point USB hub connected to a power point. how do I overcome this?

Comment: Does charging work if you plug the cable directly into the computer (instead of the hub)?

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274/ipad-displays-not-charging-when-plugged-into-usb-ports-what-can-i-do and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/ipad-charging-usb-hub

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 kind of USB hubs.

- Unpowered

Non-powered, or passive, USB hubs do not have an external power source and only pull power from the computer's USB port, limiting the maximum power to single USB (splitting).

- Powered

Powered, or active, USB hubs use an external power source to bring each hub port to the same energy level as an on-system port, but not to charge them.

- Powered with Charge capability

mostly have one (or more) of the USB ports capable of charging devices