# iPhone Not Charging When Plugged In?

Tags: iphone, charging

My device is simply not charging while connected to my Windows 8 system. I've heard of my friends having this issue too. There is no connection issue, my computer recognizes it is plugged in, but I don't think it knows what it is and it clearly doesn't allow for charging.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Does it work when connected to the *AC* or any other computer?

Answer (score 1):

Try steps at http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1476

not all ports on PCs have enough power for especially Ipads.   Try USB port at back of PC (ones directly connected to motherboard, instead of front ports or keyboard ports.   Front ones frequently have lower power delivery specs than back ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with iphone 5, But I managed to find the answer:
Force restore mode
If your iPhone 4 is hanging with an Apple logo, or exhibiting some other software problem that prevents iTunes from recognizing it, you can force it into recovery/restore mode and then use iTunes to restore the software.

If the device is powered off, plug one end of your USB cable into the iPhone 4 and leave the other end disconnected. Press down on the Home button, and keep holding it down while you plug the USB cable into your computer. After 5-10 seconds, you should see a "Please Connect to iTunes" image on the iPhone 4, and iTunes should prompt you to restore the software; follow the prompts and the instructions given above.

If the device is powered on, hold down both the power and home buttons until the device reboots and displays the "Connect to iTunes" image (generally, 5-15 seconds).
 from :https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/iPhone_4_Troubleshooting#Section_Corrupted_software

Answer (score -1):

The cords are junk.I replaced 2 already.It may or may not recognize the device.It depends on how bad your cord is.If it does recognize the device.One of your internal wires are no longer connected and is separated.Happens often.I have never had issues with a motherboard not supplying enough power.Only on a  multi-port USB hub.Maybe.

Answer (score -2):

You need to re-install "Apple Mobile Device Support". THis will the charging issue Windows users face.

Comment: Unlikely - Windows doesn't have the hardware recognition to sufficiently power an iPad. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274/ipad-displays-not-charging-when-plugged-into-usb-ports-what-can-i-do?rq=1