# Does a driver exist to step up a PC USB 3.0 port to charge an iPad at 12W?

Tags: usb, charging, power, ipad

The iPad Retina [requires 12W to charge](http://store.apple.com/au/question/answers/iphone/does-it-do-fast-charging-when-i-use-it-with-a-12w-usb-power-adapter/QD7TAKA4UAFJDHDYY).

It appears the Mac has special non-usb-standard drivers that step up the USB 3.0 port [to provide the extra power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/132713/5580) for charging.

My question is: **Does a driver exist to step up a PC USB 3.0 port to charge an iPad at 12W?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No.

The iPad charger DOES NOT use a standard USB port, but uses the USB connector to provide a "dedicated charging port". The standard based DCP can supply a maximum of 1.5A. In fact the Apple charger is a non standard device and can supply up to 2A, which it indicates to the device by specific voltages on the data pins.

A USB port supporting data is limited to 900mA.

Comment: " A USB port supporting data is limited to 900mA. " @Milliways This is not true.  USB 2.0 and USB 3.x allow for 1.5 amps of power while also supporting data transfer.  By utilizing USB-PD a USB-A port can provide 5 volts of power up to 2.4 amps while supporting data transfer, which was part of the USB spec since 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Your motherboard may have a firmware update to enable it, or add-in driver on the install CD/DVD

Ref - [iPad displays “Not Charging” when plugged into USB ports. What can I do?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274/ipad-displays-not-charging-when-plugged-into-usb-ports-what-can-i-do?rq=1)